# How to "undelete" table cell in UITableView "Edit" mode

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a bunch of cells and I would like to let user decide which are shown.

I was wondering if it is possible to somehow select cells to hide when in edit mode, so they are not displayed in normal table. But if user wants them back, he can go to edit mode and all hidden cells would show up as shaded or something and user can enable them again to be seen in normal view.

Thanks

Comment: This is not part of a normal table view, you need to implement it yourself. What you CAN do is, simply not delete the entry in your data source, and when the user wants it back simply add it again. Like here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_48

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it works but here is an idea :

If the order doesn't matter, you could have two different arrays, one for visible cells and one for invisible cells, so that when the user "deletes" a cell, you put the object in the other array.
Then for the display you could maybe have two sections in your table view, one showing visible cells and the other showing invisible ones.

Again I'm not 100% sure this is a viable solution, but I think it's worth a try.

Answer (score -1):

Its simple take an image and overlap on the cell which you want to disable. When user wants to enable that cell, from edit mode remove the image on the user click or selection.